# How does Deadpool 2 fit in the X-Men timeline!

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-origins-wolverine, deadpool-2

So by *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, the *X-Men* timeline is reset. So, Wade never met Stryker and was never made into Mutant-XI who went to fight Wolverine. Then why did Deadpool go back in time to kill him in front of Wolverine?

I know it was funny, but really confuses me about the timeline of the X-Man movies.

Comment: Deadpool is not (and never has been) in the same continuty / universe as the rest of the X-Men movie universes.

Comment: Ok, but was it ever stated by the franchise?

Comment: By which franchise? Even the X-men movie timelines don't make sense with or withou Deadpool.

Comment: So you are saying the timeline is completely chaos?

Comment: Basically yes, but Deadpool really not in the timeline of **any** pre-existing X-Men movie barring actual official confirmation. Linked quesion below which covers part of this.

Comment: @Paulie_D, is the wikipedia wrong?  " It is the eighth installment of the X-Men film series" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_(film) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_(film_series)

Comment: Installment in that it's part of **an** X-men universe...just not **the** X-Men universe.